# Water resistant -absorb -last floor

Tags: home-automation

I would like to have advices about my old home.It is old ,when it rains a lot because it is near the sea,the last floor (the floor that it is on the ground ,I dont know the exactly word ) ,it has water. Everytime it rains a lot,I am in the position to get out this water by hand. I haven't the money to cover it now the floor  so that  it will not get water when it rains. What I can use or in low price that will stop the water or to absorb  it somehow.[image]

Comment: Without knowing where the water is coming in, there won't be a good answer. It may be rising, it may come through a wall.

Comment: @Tim it comes underground...

Comment: So you're saying you have ground water (not uncommon) that is rising up through the floor?  Is that correct?  I'm not clear what the rain has to do with it.  Please edit your question and clearly describe what's going on.

Comment: [Edit] your post to include some pictures. Show us the ground floor (correct term!), what the water damage looks like, how close to the sea are you (on the beach, or a kilometer away?), what type of climate you live in, you could even go so far as to indicate the town and country you live in.

Comment: Yes it is rishing up through the floor. The ground gathers a lot of water and from down it goes inside the home.I am 100meter from sea.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the water is coming _up_ through the floor and not _under the door_? The slightest leak under that door could, unfortunately, allow water in.

Comment: It is sure that it comes from down @FreeMan. Not from door.